# How to to get the sum of the smallest N nonzero elements in a solution using cvxpy?

Tags: optimization, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I'm using cvxpy to solve a mixed integer problem using MOSEK. It has a constraint on the sum of the smallest N entries that are nonzero.

I'd like to try to get something like

```
cvxpy.sum_smallest((A @ x)[A @ x > epsilon], N) >= b
```

where

```
[A @ x > epsilon]
```

is the usual numpy-like indexing. Here A is some (m x n) matrix, x is (n x 1), b is (m x 1) and epsilon is some number slightly greater than zero and N < m.

It's not obvious to me how to do this efficiently using cvxpy.

Comment: That requires a mixed-integer model with binary variables to remember which elements of the vector are zero and which are not. Then maybe you might replace the zeros with something very large by an implication and finally take the sum_smallest of that. It will not be pretty. Maybe there is some inspiration in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html

Comment: Thanks Michal. That's an excellent idea. Do you know how I'd get an indicator variable like that? Say I have a solution vector, x, and binary vector, z, both of the same dimension. How do I enforce z is 1 when x is below a threshold?

Answer (score 1):

Solved using a boolean indicator variable, b, where b = 1 if A @ x >= epsilon.

cvxpy.sum_smallest(A @ x + (1 - b) * M)

where M is some large number.